# Sorting inputted integers into odd and even arrays

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, int

I'm a beginner to C, and am trying to sort user inputted numbers into odd and even arrays. I don't understand why my code isn't working. 
Cheers.

This is my code, I don't understand my mistake.

```
int x[]= {};
int i=0; 
int d=0;
int j=0;
int even[12]={};
int odd[12]={};

printf("Enter amount of numbers: ");  // asking user for amount of numbers
    scanf("%d", &d);

for (j=0; j<d; j++){
    printf("Enter number %d: ", i+1); // scanning input into 'x' array
        scanf("%d", x[i]);
}
printf("Even numbers: ");
for (i=0; i<d; i++) {
    if (x[i] % 2 == 0) {              // sorting into even array
        even[i]=x[i]; 
        printf("%d \n", even[i]);
    }
}
    printf("\n Odd numbers: ");
for (i=0; i<d;i++){
    if (x[i] % 2 != 0) {              // sorting into odd array
        odd[i]=x[i];
        printf("%d \n", odd[i]);
    }
}
```

This error message keeps coming up:

```
$ ./main
Enter amount of numbers: 4
Enter number 1: 6
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", x[i]);` should be `scanf("%d", &x[i]);`

Comment: There is no space for 4 integers in `int x[]= {};`.

Comment: @Blaze that seems to work, but it isn't reading the numbers into the odd and even arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int x[]= {};` doesn't work because it would hold no elements. But initializing it with `{}` doesn't work in C anyway, do this instead:

```
int x[24] = {0}; // first element explicitely set to 0, the rest default-initialized to 0
```

You also need to put `{0}` for `even` and `odd`. If it's compiling for you with `{}` then it's possible that you're compiling it as a C++ program, or perhaps your compiler just tolerates it anyway (but it won't work on every C compiler).

`scanf` needs the address of the `int`, so instead of `scanf("%d", x[i]);` you need `scanf("%d", &x[i]);`. But `i` is the wrong iterator for this `for (j = 0; j < d; j++)` loop. Instead do this:

```
for (j = 0; j < d; j++) {
    printf("Enter number %d: ", j + 1); // scanning input into 'x' array
    scanf("%d", &x[j]);
}
```

---

Also note that the way you're doing this, half the array will be left at `0`. So for instance if I imputted the values `1` through `6`, then `odd` contains the values `1 0 3 0 5 0`.